# August, and still no LTS upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, 18.04

I have Xubuntu 16.04 LTS installed:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

And I thought by now that the LTS upgrade to 18.04.01 would be possible, due to [the announcement last month](https://xubuntu.org/news/18-04-1-released/), however:

```
# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Is there a delay in releasing 18.04 LTS through the `do-release-upgrade` route?

Comment: Apparently if you select "For any new version" for "*Notify me of a new Ubuntu version*" in Softwares & Updates, you'll get the option to upgrade to 18,04, but if you select "For long-term support versions" you won't.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

the `-d` flag at the end of the command, it will upgrade to the current development version. Which might or might not be 18.04.

Comment: `-d` won't force the upgrade, it will upgrade to the current development version. Which might or might not be 18.04.

Comment: @SorenA you're right, thanks for the correction